# Using an Arduino to read data from an ADS1113

Tags: arduino, adc, integrated-circuit, i2c

I have an [ADS1113](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1113.pdf) ADC connected to an Arduino using the I2C protocol. I'm just trying to read the analog data from the ADC.

I have 5 volts connected to the AIN0 and AIN1 inputs. When I check the `Wire.endTransmission()` value I keep getting a 0 back, meaning the data was successfully transmitted.

Yet, when requesting 4 bytes I keep getting this, even when I change the voltage at the AIN0 and AIN1 inputs:

[image]

I am pretty new to using I2C and learning how to setup particular ICs from reading the [data sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1113.pdf). The *QuickStart Guide* is on page 35 (I tried posting a pic of what it says, but I don't have high enough reputation to post more than two links).

My question is: how do I obtain the second and third byte values? Or am I completely off and not even supposed to be reading the data from the conversion register?

```
#include <Wire.h>

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  Wire.begin(); 
}

void loop()
{
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);             //compare to ADC data
  float voltage = sensorValue * (5.0 / 1023.0);
  Serial.println(voltage);
  Serial.println();
  
  Wire.beginTransmission(B1001000);         //Address of ADC
  Wire.write(1);                          
  int ack = Wire.endTransmission();       
  Serial.print("I2C = ");
  Serial.print(ack);                      
  Serial.println();
  delay(15); 
  
  Wire.requestFrom(B1001000,4,1); //Requesting 4 bytes 
  while(Wire.available()){
    float RAW = Wire.read();
    float RAW_voltage = (RAW*4.096/32768.0);
    Serial.print("Raw ADC value = ");
    Serial.print(RAW);
    Serial.print("\tVoltage = ");
    Serial.print(RAW_voltage);
    Serial.println();
  }
  delay(1000); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the datasheet for single-ended measurement you should connect AIN1 pin to ground.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean about 4bytes.
Your code is correct and received all requested 4 bytes 1 by 1

**this loop run four times and received all data from the I2c Slave.**

```
 while(Wire.available()){    



    float RAW = Wire.read();  <<--------------- at this line 
    float RAW_voltage = (RAW*4.096/32768.0);
    Serial.print("Raw ADC value = ");
    Serial.print(RAW);
    Serial.print("\tVoltage = ");
    Serial.print(RAW_voltage);
    Serial.println();
  }
```

But if your ADC values are not changed that means your sensor ADS1113 not configure/working correctly first of all check your sensor output.

Comment: I thought maybe I was requesting 4 bytes of information from the ADC. Ahhh ok, thanks. What do you mean by checking the sensor output though?

Comment: Ohh, i think you are using an external sensor or somthing like voltage source

Answer (score 0):

I think the ADC tells you the difference between AIN0 and AIN1.
Since both are 5V, the difference is 0V.